# Error in onPostExecute that try to show image in gridview

Tags: android, json, image, gridview

I made gridview application that get path of image from json. I create at a SimpleAdapter that first time I just want my gridview show the image in drawable. but when I run my application it shows me an error in onPostExecute.

How can I show Image in gridview using image in drawable or image from json?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String strUrl = "http://192.168.10.104/adchara1/";
GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);        
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int positon,
                long id) {
             HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) gridView.getAdapter().getItem(positon);
             String imgPath = (String) hm.get("photo"); //get downloaded image path
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("ClickedImagePath", imgPath ); //put image link in intent.
             startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
  String data = "";
  InputStream iStream = null;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        iStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        iStream.close();
        data = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}

/** AsyncTask to download json data */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
     String data = "";
     InputStream iStream = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
        GridViewLoaderTask gridViewLoaderTask = new GridViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        gridViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
private class GridViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

    JSONObject jObject;
    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating json parser class
        CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

        // A list object to store the parsed countries list
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try{
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "frame","photo"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.iv_frame,R.id.iv_photo};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
       // SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        return adapter;

    }

    /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String frameUrl = (String) hm.get("frame_path");
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("photo_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("frame_path", frameUrl);
            hm.put("photo_path",imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }
    }
} 

public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context myContext;
    public SimpleAdapter(Context _myContext){
        myContext = _myContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout, null);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        return view;
    }

}

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream = null;
            String imgUrl;
            String frameUrl;
            imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("photo_path");
            frameUrl = (String) hm[0].get("frame_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            URL urlFrame;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);
                urlFrame = new URL(frameUrl);
                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+ position + ".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                // Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("photo", tmpFile.getPath());
                hmBitmap.put("frame", tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position", position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        String path = (String) result.get("photo");
        String framePath = (String) result.get("frame");
        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) gridView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
        hm.put("photo",path);
        hm.put("frame", framePath);
        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class CountryJSONParser {

// Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array
        jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("countries");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
    // where each json object represent a country
    return getCountries(jsonArray);
}

private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
    int countryCount = jCountries.length();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> country = null;

    // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object
    for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
        try {
            // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country
            country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return countryList;
}

// Parsing the Country JSON object
private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

    HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String photo="";
    String frame ="";

    try {
        photo = jCountry.getString("photo");
        frame = jCountry.getString("frame");

        country.put("frame", R.drawable.blank);
        country.put("frame_path", frame);

        country.put("photo", R.drawable.blank);
        country.put("photo_path", photo);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return country;
}

}
```

Error in logcat

```
11-02 08:26:48.118: W/dalvikvm(11384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bee1f8)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at com.myapp.MainActivity$GridViewLoaderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:187)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at com.myapp.MainActivity$GridViewLoaderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-02 08:26:48.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11384):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".DisplayActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to NullPointerException raised by GridView. Because you are starting Download task before creating gridview object and by the time the object gets created, onPostExecute() is called and it is raising error. You first create gridview object and give call DownloadTask. I found that error from your code and hope it helps you.

Comment: could you please correct it cuz I try it from tutorial. the first this project is Listview and I customize to gridview

Answer (score 0):

Write below Code line

```
// Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

// Starting the download process
downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
```

after

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: would you need a full project

Comment: if you trying to fix this project, please let me know

Comment: This is my localhost. In android we can't use http://localhost/adchara1 so we need to change localhost our to computer ip. In myapp project I give u a database and php already. So u need to create localhost name adchara1.